# Does XSLT have a Split() function?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xslt, split

I have a string in a node and I'd like to split the string on '?' and return the last item in the array.

For example, in the block below:

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        /newpage.aspx?<xsl:value-of select="someNode"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    Link text
</a>
```

I'd like to split the `someNode` value.

Edit: 
Here's the VB.Net that I use to load the Xsl for my Asp.Net page:

```
Dim xslDocPath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/someXslt.xsl")
Dim myXsltSettings As New XsltSettings()
Dim myXMLResolver As New XmlUrlResolver()

myXsltSettings.EnableScript = True
myXsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction = True

myXslDoc = New XslCompiledTransform(False)
myXslDoc.Load(xslDocPath, myXsltSettings, myXMLResolver)

Dim myStringBuilder As New StringBuilder()
Dim myXmlWriter As XmlWriter = Nothing

Dim myXmlWriterSettings As New XmlWriterSettings()
myXmlWriterSettings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto
myXmlWriterSettings.Indent = True
myXmlWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = True

myXmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(myStringBuilder, myXmlWriterSettings)

myXslDoc.Transform(xmlDoc, argumentList, myXmlWriter)

Return myStringBuilder.ToString()
```

**Update:** here's [an example of splitting XML on a particular node](http://gist.github.com/360186)

Comment: Does not really have anything to do with ASP.Net

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use a recursive method:

```
<xsl:template name="output-tokens">
    <xsl:param name="list" /> 
    <xsl:variable name="newlist" select="concat(normalize-space($list), ' ')" /> 
    <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before($newlist, ' ')" /> 
    <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($newlist, ' ')" /> 
    <id>
        <xsl:value-of select="$first" /> 
    </id>
    <xsl:if test="$remaining">
        <xsl:call-template name="output-tokens">
            <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$remaining" /> 
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Note that if there are no tokens in the list, this template will nevertheless output an empty `<id>` element, instead of no `<id>` elements.

Comment: I was quite excited about trying this, but Firefox unfortunately says : "Error during XSLT transformation: XSLT Stylesheet (possibly) contains a recursion.". Yes, Firefox it's supposed to be recursive...duh...

Answer (score 12):

If you can use XSLT 2.0 or higher, you can use `tokenize(string, separator)`:

```
tokenize("XPath is fun", "\s+")
Result: ("XPath", "is", "fun")
```

See the [w3schools XPath function reference](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp).

By default, .NET does not support XSLT 2.0, let alone XSLT 3.0. The only known 2.0+ processors for .NET are [Saxon for .NET](http://saxonica.com) with [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/), [Exselt](http://exselt.net), a .NET XSLT 3.0 processor currently in beta, and [XMLPrime](http://xmlprime.com) XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: The only down-side is that it requires XSLT 2.0 :-(

Comment: yeah, i'm getting a "'tokenize()' is an unknown XSLT function." error

Comment: Which processor are you using?

Answer (score 8):

I ended up using the [`substring-after()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms256455(VS.80).aspx) function. Here's what worked for me:

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        /newpage.aspx?<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(someNode, '?')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    Link text
</a>
```

Even after setting the version of my XSLT to 2.0, I still got a "`'tokenize()' is an unknown XSLT function.`" error when trying to use `tokenize()`.

Comment: I wish I had kept the code, but at my previous employer I wrote a xslt 1.0 function to get the n-th token of a string. It's not too difficult once you wrap your head around the concept functional programming

Answer (score 6):

Adding another possibility, if your template engine supports [EXSLT](http://www.exslt.org/), then you could use [tokenize()](http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html) from that.

For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
                extension-element-prefixes="str">

...
  <a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:text>/newpage.aspx?</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(someNode)[2]"/>
    </xsl:attribute>              
  </a>
...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Have you used this successfully in .net?

Answer (score 3):

.NET doesn't support XSLT 2.0, unfortunately.  I'm pretty sure that it supports EXSLT, which has a [split()](http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/split/str.split.html) function.  Microsoft has an [older page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468553.aspx) on its implementation of EXSLT.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a template using `string-before` and `string-after` functions and use it across. I wrote a [blog](http://lavgupta.com/2008/05/xsl-template-to-split-to-string.html) on this.

Finally came up with a xslt template that would split a delimited string into substrings.
I don’t claim it’s the smartest script, but surely solves my problem.

Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="Paths/Item">
<xsl:call-template name="SplitText">
<xsl:with-param name="inputString" select="Path"/>
<xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="Delimiter"/>
</xsl:call-template>
<br/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="SplitText">
<xsl:param name="inputString"/>
<xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="contains($inputString, $delimiter)">
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($inputString,$delimiter)"/>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping = "no"> </xsl:text>
<xsl:call-template name="SplitText">
<xsl:with-param name="inputString" select="substring-after($inputString,$delimiter)"/>
<xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$inputString = ''">
<xsl:text></xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="$inputString"/>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML file (to be transformed) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="textSpliter.xslt"?>
<Paths>
  <Item>
    <Path>C:\ProgramFiles\SomeWierdSoftware</Path>
    <Delimiter>\</Delimiter>
  </Item>
</Paths>
```

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 1.0 doesn't have a split function per se, but you could potentially achieve what you're trying to do with the substring-before and substring-after functions.

Alternatively, if you're using a Microsoft XSLT engine, you could use inline C#.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, if you're doing this with 1.0, and you really need a split/tokenise, you need the [xslt extensions](http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/).

Comment: interesting, how would i use that in the example above?