# Removing white space inside quotes in XSLT

Tags: xslt, whitespace

I'm trying to format a table from XML. Lets say I have this line in the XML

```
<country>Dominican Republic</country>
```

I would like to get my table to look like this

```
<td class="country DominicanRepublic">Dominican Republic</td>
```

I've tried this:

```
<td class="country {country}"><xsl:value-of select="country"/></td>
```

then this:

```
<xsl:element name="td">
 <xsl:attribute name="class">
  <xsl:text>country </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(country)"/>
 </xsl:attribute>
<xsl:value-of select="country"/>
</xsl:element>
```

The `normalize-space()` doesn't remove the space between the two parts of the name and I can't use `<xsl:strip-space elements="country"/>` because I need the space when I display the name inside the table cell.

How can I strip the space from the value inside the class, but not the text in the cell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the **[translate()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate)** function to replace spaces ' ' with nothing '':

```
<xsl:element name="td">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:text>country </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(country,' ','')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
</xsl:element>
```

You can use `normalize-space()`, which will remove any leading and trailing white space and convert multiple spaces between characters into a single space.  Then, send the results through `translate()` to replace any remaining spaces:

```
<xsl:element name="td">
   <xsl:attribute name="class">
    <xsl:text>country </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space(country),' ','')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(country)"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I'm still learning XSL, so thanks for the help :)

Comment: Actually the XML is a feed from another site, and there is white space in front of the text. The translate function doesn't remove that, any solution for that? I'm not sure how to stack up functions, like using normalize on country after the translate.

Comment: If you use translate to remove spaces it should do so for all spaces. Are you sure it isn't tab, carriage return, or other white space?  You could use `normalize-space()` and send the results to `translate()`.  I'll update the answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to split your string by whitespaces recursively, have a look at this topic:
[Does XSLT have a Split() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136500/does-xslt-have-a-split-function)

Or you can try this replace function implementation: [http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025173545/http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx)