# Filter a CSV list in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to convert xml elements whose content is a csv list of identifiers, the exact form doesn't matter. I want to exclude every item that contains the character "/". The best I've come up with is

```
translate(./someElement, ",*/*", "")
```

but this has at least two problems; I'm pretty sure that xsl doesn't accept wildcards, and "," is an illegal character in xpaths.

Is there a straightforward way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: Could you give us an example of the input and output you want? I'm not entirely sure I'm grasping the question here.

If you're asking what I think you might be, then maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136500/does-xslt-have-a-split-function could help; the basic idea would be to recursively split the string at the comma character, but output only those substrings that don't have a slash in them (checked using contains(), say.)

Comment: Oh, also, if you're using XSLT 2, have a look into tokenize(): http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1205

Comment: For clarification: Given an element with text content that's actually a csv list of items, say 

   a,aa,a/b,1,1/2,...

I want to remove all the items that contain /, leaving in this case:

    a,aa,1

The linked example does seem to be along the right lines, thanks. i'm doing this in .Net though so in context, using an extension object that references a VB function that already exists is easier.

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 2 you can say :

```
 tokenize($s,",")[not(contains(.,"/"))]
```