# Simple XSLT template

Tags: templates, xslt

There is XML document:

```
<data>how;many;i;can;tell;you</data>
```

Need to get XML **using XSLT version 1**:

```
 <manydata>
     <onedata>how</onedata>
     <onedata>many</onedata>
     <onedata>i</onedata>
     <onedata>can</onedata>
     <onedata>tell</onedata>
     <onedata>you</onedata>
   </manydata>
```

How I can  do it?

UPDATE:
Output format must be **XML**.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the shortest so far solution that is also simpler than what others have offered. :)

Comment: This is almost the most answered FAQ about XSLT. Some of the duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136500/does-xslt-have-a-split-function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336424/does-xslt-have-split-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This recursive solution is probably one of the shortest possible**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="data">
  <manydata><xsl:apply-templates/></manydata>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="tokenize">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
   <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">
      <onedata>
       <xsl:value-of select=
        "substring-before(concat($pText,';'),';')"/>
      </onedata>
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
       <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
        "substring-after($pText,';')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document;**

```
<data>how;many;i;can;tell;you</data>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<manydata>
   <onedata>how</onedata>
   <onedata>many</onedata>
   <onedata>i</onedata>
   <onedata>can</onedata>
   <onedata>tell</onedata>
   <onedata>you</onedata>
</manydata>
```

Comment: Is it XSLT 1.0? There is no "tokenize()  function" in XSLT 1.0 !

Comment: The named template is called `tokenize`; this isn't the same as the `tokenize` function. This will work just fine in XSLT 1.0

Comment: @Grienders: Yes, this *is* XSLT 1.0. And the name of a template has nothing to do with the name of any (standard or not) XPath function.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="data">
    <manydata>
        <!-- 
            empty <manydata/> will be generated,
            if <data/> without child text() 
        -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    </manydata>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data/text()">
    <!-- start point for recursion -->
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-string">
        <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="';'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="text()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize-string">
    <xsl:param name="separator"/>
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="string-before-separator" 
        select="substring-before( $string, $separator )"/>
    <onedata>
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- if $separator presents in $string take first piece -->
            <xsl:when test="$string-before-separator">
                <xsl:value-of select="$string-before-separator"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- take whole $string, if no $separator in the $string -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </onedata>
    <!-- recursive call, if separator was found -->
    <xsl:if test="$string-before-separator">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-string">
            <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="string" 
                select="substring-after( $string, $separator )"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="data">
   <xsl:element name="manydata">
      <xsl:call-template name="splitsemicolons">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="text()" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="splitsemicolons">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text,';')">
        <xsl:element name="onedata">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,';')" />
         </xsl:element>
         <xsl:call-template name="splitsemicolons">
           <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,';')" />
         </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:element name="onedata">
           <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
         </xsl:element>
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This uses a named template that is called recursively, each time outputting what's before the first `;`, and calling itself with everything after the first `;`. If there isn't a `;`, it just outputs whatever's left as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [XSLT extension library](http://exslt.org/str/index.html) to get the tokenize function. Here is how the final code will look like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <manydata>
 <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(data, ';')">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
   </xsl:for-each> 
 </manydata>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please note you will have to import the extension library into you XSLT using:

```
<xsl:import href="path/str.xsl" />
```

before you use the library functions.

Comment: I cann't use XSLT extension library. I can use XSLT version  1 only.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong.. the extension library is compatible with version 1.0