# How to split values of an xml attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have a tag in xml like

`<Radio values="Husband~Husband|Wife~Wife|Son~Son|Daughter~Daughter|Father~Father|Mother~Mother"></Radio>`

Now I have to split the attribute into `Husband, Wife, Son, Daughter, Father, Mother` and use each one as a value for the `value` attribute in `<input type = "radio" value = "<the value i get from the list>" />`

Can anyone give me an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Based on research, appears you need a recursive template:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136500/does-xslt-have-a-split-function
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336424/does-xslt-have-split-function

Comment: What language you are using? C#? Javascript? Java? PHP? etc etc? :)

Comment: @Mujtaba Hassan: I am writing XSL to generate an HTML Output.

Comment: No problem. I couldn't post it as an answer because stackoverflow thought it was too simple. Maybe if I add more characters I guess.