# Splitting up and transforming delimited string in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

This is a sample of the XML I want to transform:

```
<dsQueryResponse>
  <Rows>
    <Row Contacts="#111;#Smith, John;#112;#Sue, Mary;#113;#Jones, Rick" />
    <Row Contacts="#114;#Lee, Thomas;#115;#Richards, Kate" />
  </Rows>
</dsQueryResponse>
```

Using XSLT, how do I split this up so that it the output looks like:

```
<div>
  <span>#111;#Smith, John</span>
  <span>#112;#Sue, Mary</span>
  <span>#113;#Jones, Rick</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>#114;#Lee, Thomas</span>
  <span>#115;#Richards, Kate</span>
</div>
```

The `;` being used as a delimiter while having each set contain it is what is confusing me.

---

**Edit:**
Yes, I am aware of this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336424/does-xslt-have-split-function).
I have tried it but it is not splitting the way I need it to.
`;` is a delimiter *and* is also part of what is being split.

Comment: @Tomalak This question is  little more complicated than that.

Comment: @DanielHaley This question is little more complicated than that.

Comment: I have seen that post and have tried, but it is splitting it too much. For example, `#111`, `#Smith, John`, `#112`, `#Sue, Mary` **(4)** instead of `#111;#Smith, John`, `#112;#Sue, Mary` **(2)**

Comment: Which specific XSLT 1.0 processor are you using?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I don't know to be honest. Just whatever SharePoint 2010 is using I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/dsQueryResponse">
    <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="Rows/Row">
            <div>
               <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@Contacts"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="';'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $delimiter) and contains(substring-after($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)">
            <span>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
            </span>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after(substring-after($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <span>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </span>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**:
If there is XML hell, the authors of your source document shall burn in it.

Comment: Hahaha! Great this works! (The XML is generated by SharePoint. Not the most easiest of XMLs of deal with that's for sure haha)