# Two names in one element (XSLT)

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello I'm trying it again, becouse I can't find an answer to my question...

I have this XML input

```
<Name> Name1, Name2</Name>
```

And in XML output I need to get this

```
<NameOfFirstOne>Name1 </NameOfFirstOne>
 <NameOfSecondOne>Name2 </NameOfSecondOne>
```

But if I do value of I always get both names, but I just need one. So what can I do with it?

Comment: use `substring-before` and `substring-after` functions.

Comment: [Does xslt have split() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336424/does-xslt-have-split-function)

Answer (score 1):

If you have XPath 3.1 (i.e. XSLT 2.0), then you can use the `tokenize()` function for splitting your string by a specified separator string:

```
<xsl:template match="Name">
    <xsl:variable name="names" select="tokenize(text(),', ')"/>
    <NameOfFirstOne>
        <xsl:value-of select="$names[1]"/>
    </NameOfFirstOne>
    <NameOfSecondOne>
        <xsl:value-of select="$names[2]"/>
    </NameOfSecondOne>
</xsl:template>
```