# xslt mapping to find substring between

Tags: xslt, substring, xslt-1.0

I have my string as below

```
<Text>Pack:NA Lead:20 Dimension:235</Text>
```

And need to map

```
NA to outputfield1
20 to outputfield2
235 to outputfield3
```

How to do this correctly in xslt mapping where the values 'NA,20,235' could be different each time?

I could only see substring component which takes length as second parameter.
That leads requires several steps to achieve this.

Any better solution to just take the value between `Lead:` and `Dimension` for outputfield2?

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you using? If you have tried any code, please share it? Also are the output values going to be values associated with `Pack:`, `Lead:` and `Dimension:` or these too change?

Comment: xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" ,

Comment: yes always the input have Pack:, Lead: and Dimension:[only the values may change]

Comment: If you are stuck with XSLT 1.0 as the only option then splitting the string for `space` character and then using `substring-after` would probably be the way to go. If you can use XSLT 2.0, then it has built in functions which will make this task easy.

Comment: how to split the string for space - any function to use that ?

Comment: There is no built-in function in XSLT 1.0. You need to write a recursive template to split the string. Here is a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336424/does-xslt-have-split-function) to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the Pack value, you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(Text, 'Pack:'), ' ')" />
```

To extract the Lead value, use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(Text, 'Lead:'), ' ')" />
```

To extract the Dimension:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Text, 'Dimension:')" />
```