# How to set split value in XSL 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need to set split values in different  parameters.My response like below.

```
  `<Response >
     <Result>100002 0 Testing 1500.00 YES</Result>
  </Response>`
```

What i need is to get above split value in different result like below .[please note i have hard coded "select="100002" " values]

```
          ` <xsl:element name="ns1:Response">
              <xsl:value-of select="100002">
           </xsl:element>`

     `<xsl:element name="ns1:amount">
              <xsl:value-of select="0 ">
           </xsl:element>`

    `<xsl:element name="ns1:name">
              <xsl:value-of select="Testing  ">
           </xsl:element>`

   `<xsl:element name="ns1:Amount">
              <xsl:value-of select="1500.00">
           </xsl:element>`

 `<xsl:element name="ns1:Other">
              <xsl:value-of select="Yes">
           </xsl:element>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
<xsl:template match="Result">
        <xsl:call-template name="abc">
            <xsl:with-param name="data" select="."></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="abc">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
    <xsl:element name="ns1:Response">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($data, ' ')"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="ns1:amount">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($data, ' '), ' ')"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="ns1:name">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($data, ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="ns1:Amount">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after($data, ' '), ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="ns1:Other">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after($data, ' '), ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: hii @Rupesh my issue is these results will change every time as below.

`<Response >
     <Result>10000209 0 Resting 100.00 NO</Result>
  </Response>`

`<Response >
     <Result>100002 8 Reduce 1900.00 NO</Result>
  </Response>` 
 
`<Response >
     <Result>99999 7 Root 1200.00 MayBe</Result>
  </Response>`

Comment: @Kasun Updated as per your requirement

Comment: hi @Rupesh is there any possibility separate this kind of results.
 <return>0~3~889499~21/12/2017</return>
 i need separate these results like as below
<xsl:element name="ns1:amount">
              <xsl:value-of select="0 ">
           </xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="ns1:Cost">
              <xsl:value-of select="3 ">
           </xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="ns1:No">
              <xsl:value-of select="889499 ">
           </xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="ns1:Date">
              <xsl:value-of select="21/12/2017">
           </xsl:element>

Comment: @Kasun, Just change `' '` with `'~'`, above condition is written for `space` so change it to `~`.

Comment: @Kasun, if this answer solved your query, than accept answer. so this question can be closed.

Comment: have a problem again '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">; <s:Body> <MYResponse xmlns="Host.Org/">; <FinalResult>@@ 23333333 -89 WrongData $$</FinalResult> </MYResponse> </s:Body> </s:Envelope>' This not working using above method any idea thanks

Comment: have you added namespace in xslt?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty topics to a split function already. E.g.: [Split implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336424/does-xslt-have-split-function)

This should help you out.
WithRefering to that you should just need a result template looking like this:

```
<xsl:template match="result">
    <xsl:call-template name="splitfunction">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
        <xsl:with-param name="seperator" select=" "/>
    </xsl:call:template>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks.have to looking into that

Comment: An alternative would be to use a loop over the result of [the function tokenize][2]. Depends what you prefer.
  [2]: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize