# xsl: how to split strings?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to split an address on semicolons (`;`) into rows separated by `<br />`:

e.g. if `address`=`123 Elm Street`, I want to output `123 Elm Street`,

but if `address`=`123 Elm Street;PO Box 222`, I want to output

```
123 Elm Street<br />PO Box 222
```

and if `address`=`123 Elm Street;PO Box 222;c/o James Jones`, I want to output

```
123 Elm Street<br />PO Box 222<br />c/o James Jones
```

Is there a way to do this? (probably easy but I'm not that familiar with XSLT)

The plain XSL selector is

```
<xsl:value-of select="address"/>
```

and I would like to modify this XSLT fragment to split on semicolon.

---

**update**: Apparently the answer involves the use of `<xsl:call-template>` and the functions `substring-before()` and `substring-after()`.

But I'm a beginner to XSLT and I could really use some help for how to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does XSLT have a Split() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136500/does-xslt-have-a-split-function)

Comment: maybe it is a near-duplicate, but I can't figure out how to apply the answers to that question, to my problem.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750184/looping-through-multiple-sequences-from-strtokenize

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I. Plain XSLT 1.0 solution:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="split">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">
   <xsl:if test="not($pText=.)">
    <br />
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select=
    "substring-before(concat($pText,';'),';')"/>
   <xsl:call-template name="split">
    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
     "substring-after($pText, ';')"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>123 Elm Street;PO Box 222;c/o James Jones</t>
```

**produces the wanted, corrected result**:

```
123 Elm Street<br />PO Box 222<br />c/o James Jones
```

**II. FXSL 1 (for XSLT 1.0):**

Here we just use the **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)** template `str-map` (and do not have to write recursive template for the 999th time):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
xmlns:testmap="testmap"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl f testmap"
>
   <xsl:import href="str-dvc-map.xsl"/>

   <testmap:testmap/>

   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="vTestMap" select="document('')/*/testmap:*[1]"/>
     <xsl:call-template name="str-map">
       <xsl:with-param name="pFun" select="$vTestMap"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select=
       "'123 Elm Street;PO Box 222;c/o James Jones'"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="replace" mode="f:FXSL"
         match="*[namespace-uri() = 'testmap']">
      <xsl:param name="arg1"/>

      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="not($arg1=';')">
        <xsl:value-of select="$arg1"/>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise><br /></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the same, wanted correct result is produced**:

```
123 Elm Street<br/>PO Box 222<br/>c/o James Jones
```

**III. Using XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,';')">
   <xsl:sequence select="."/>
   <xsl:if test="not(position() eq last())"><br /></xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>123 Elm Street;PO Box 222;c/o James Jones</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
123 Elm Street<br />PO Box 222<br />c/o James Jones
```

Comment: could you explain the `not($pText=.)` syntax? what is the `.` doing?

Comment: @Jason-S: `.` in XSLT (and in XPath) means the current node (context node). `not($pText=.)` is `true()` if the string value of the parameter `$pText` is not equal to the string value of the current node -- we want to output  `<br />` only in this case, otherwise our output will start with `<br />`

Comment: Can I pass an already existing variable to the param name="pText"?

Comment: @Perdomoff, Yes, in XSLT the arguments supplied in the `select` attribute of `<xsl:with-param ...>` can be any XPath expression and a variable reference is a valid XPath expression. The same is true for the supplying values to the arguments when calling an `<xsll:function> in XSLT 2.0 and later versions.

Comment: This did work, thank you.  Can I pass a variable from another xsl file?

Comment: @Perdomoff, Yes if its global (defined as a child of `<xsl:stylesheet>` and if this other XSLT stylesheet is imported/included or imports/includes. I would recommend watching my Pluralsight course "XSLT 2.0 and 1.0 Foundations" https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1

Answer (score 5):

If your XSLT processor supports [EXSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXSLT), you can use [str:tokenize](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html), otherwise, the link contains an implementation using functions like substring-before.

Comment: how do I find out? My XSLT processor is a web browser, either Firefox 3.6 or Safari 5.0

Comment: @Jason S - in that case, you cannot depend on that and you need to supply the function yourself; the implementation is available at the linked http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/str.tokenize.template.xsl

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750184/looping-through-multiple-sequences-from-strtokenize