# Looping through multiple sequences from str:tokenize()

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have similar incoming XML from some hardware:

```
<invoice>
  <field name="item">Item 1;Item 2;Item 3</field>
  <field name="price">32.0;192.2;12.0</field>
  <field name="quantity">1;4;2</field>
</invoice>
```

Which I need to convert similar to this:

```
<invoice>
  <item>
    <desc>Item 1</desc>
    <price>32.0</price>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
  </item>
  <item>
    <desc>Item 1</desc>
    <price>192.0</price>
    <quantity>4</quantity>
  </item>
  <item>
    <desc>Item 3</desc>
    <price>12.0</price>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
  </item>     
</invoice>
```

At the moment I've experimented with str:tokenize(), but the main problem is constructing a simple loop. My knowledge about XSLT is very basic and my work in progress is about that far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="inovice">
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="';'"/>
    <xsl:param name="desc" select="str:tokenize(field[@name='item'],$separator)"/>
    <xsl:param name="price" select="str:tokenize(field[@name='price'],$separator)"/>
    <xsl:param name="quantity" select="str:tokenize(field[@name='quantity'],$separator)"/>
    <xsl:param name="count" select="count($desc)"/>
    <!-- some loop goes here -->
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple XSLT 2.0 stylesheet that iterates over all items and selects the corresponding prices/quantities according to the current position, could look like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="invoice">
    <xsl:variable name="fields" select="field"/>
    <invoice>
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(field[@name='item'], ';')">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <item>
          <desc>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </desc>
          <price>
            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($fields[@name='price'], ';')[position()=$pos]"/>
          </price>
          <quantity>
            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($fields[@name='quantity'], ';')[position()=$pos]"/>
          </quantity>          
        </item>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </invoice>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to use XSLT 1.0 together with the EXSLT extension module *strings*, the stylesheet must be modified only slighly:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
  extension-element-prefixes="str">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="invoice">
    <xsl:variable name="fields" select="field"/>
    <invoice>
      <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(field[@name='item'], ';')">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <item>
          <desc>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </desc>
          <price>
            <xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize($fields[@name='price'], ';')[position()=$pos]"/>
          </price>
          <quantity>
            <xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize($fields[@name='quantity'], ';')[position()=$pos]"/>
          </quantity>          
        </item>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </invoice>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me the insight. It does exactly whats needed.

I used xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" and replaced tokenize with str:tokenize. Otherwise Xalan gave errors.

Comment: I've no time to check my thoughts, but as I understand if I need to specify xmlns:str, then I'm not using XSLT-2.0 but 1.0. I thought Xalan can handle 2.0.

Comment: As far as I know, Xalan supports XSLT 1.0 only. If you want to use the EXSLT extensions, you must declare the namespaces of the required modules, and list these namespaces in attribute _extension-element-prefixes_ of xsl:stylesheet.

Comment: I switched to Saxon HE library to get XSLT 2.0.