# How to display image thumbnail instead in umbraco xslt?

Tags: image, xslt, thumbnails, umbraco

Is there any way to display image thumb in xslt in umbraco?

Or I just need to chop the umbracoFile value and put '_thumb' in there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are correct in your assumption that you just need to split on the umbracoFile value and stick "_thumb" in there.

This question has a solution or two for splitting strings: [xsl: how to split strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845660/xsl-how-to-split-strings)

You would need the "Plain XSLT 1.0 solution" as Umbraco uses XSLT 1.0, or you could use the EXSLT library which is I think is available n the Umbraco project.