# split string and make elements in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I want to split a string and reproduce the content in different tags

### Input

```
<Sample>8.1 Learning XSLT in 24 hours, 198</Sample>
```

### Output

```
<Sample><number>8.1</number><title>Learning XSLT in 24 hours,</title><pages>198</pages></Sample>
```

Note:I want to split the data based on the space.

Thanks,
Muthu

Comment: Here is a [link to a similar answer on stackoverflow.com][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845660/xsl-how-to-split-strings

Comment: the comma sepeartor may or may not come. I want to split based on the space alone not with any other delimiter