# Splitting data by delimiter

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I remember that in Visual Basic a function `Split()` exists that divides a string by a particular character.

Now I am programming in XSLT and I would like to use a similar function, but I don't know XSLT very well.

In attachment I put xml code:

```
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
        <VICINITY>TARANTO</VICINITY>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>Porto industriale esterno;Meda elastica</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
        <VICINITY>TARANTO</VICINITY>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>Porto industriale esterno;Meda elastica</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
        <VICINITY>TARANTO</VICINITY>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>Porto industriale esterno;Meda elastica</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
        <VICINITY>TARANTO</VICINITY>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>MAR GRANDE;Porto industriale interno;Accesso al IV sporgente;All 341;Radice IV sporgente (Ant)</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
        <VICINITY>TARANTO</VICINITY>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>MAR GRANDE;Porto industriale interno;Accesso al IV sporgente;All 341;Circa 700 m a NNW dell'Ant(Post)</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
```

i would like to see:

```
TARANTO
<br />
Porto industriale esterno
-Meda elastica
-Meda elastica
-Meda elastica
<br />
Mar Grande
-Porto industriale interno
--Accesso al IV sporgente
---All 341
----Radice IV sporgente (Ant)
----Circa 700 m a NNW dell'Ant(Post)
<br />
```

as a tree from `<ITA_LIGHT_NAME>` using a function similar to `Split()` but in XSLT. Thanks.

Comment: - for each child is necessary use -

Comment: With your input XML this is quite difficult, especially if you don't know XSLT very well. (There is no `Split()` function in XSLT.) **1)** Can you do anything about the XML? **2)** Are other languages than XSLT an option? **3)** If you must use XSLT, what XSLT engine (name and version) are you using?

Comment: only xslt version 1.0 and i dont know different languige at moment.

Comment: I mean the *XSLT engine*, not the XSLT language version. And I asked more than one question.

Comment: You need to use a recursive template like in the following duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845660/xsl-how-to-split-strings

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the desired output, it is not just a matter of split...

Still, writing a template as suggested Matthew Green would works. However, if you have access to Java, calling an external Java function would make it much easier.

```
public String splitString(String myStringToSplit, String delimiter)
{
    String[] mySplittedString = myStringToSplit.split(delimiter);
    String returnString = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < mySplittedString.length; i++)
    {
        returnString += mySplittedString[i] + "<br/>";
    }

    return returnString;
}
```

And in XSLT, after declaring your java namespace :

```
<xsl:value-of select="namespace:splitString('your;String;To;Split', ';')"/>
```

This is fully compatible with XSLT 1.0.

Now to get your desired output, once again as this is too complex algorithm for XSLT, I would parse the entire XML and concatenate each node delimited by a specific char for each element into one String than I would send it to a Java function which would return the tree for me. This way, it'll be easier to check for already existing VICINITY, etc. and to make sure you don't have duplicated node.