# Trying to add line breaks inside a template in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSLT file that is rendering an HTML page, I am trying to split the string by using `;` as the delimiter and then adding line breaks every EVEN break. I have my code below, it doesn't seem to work, the line breaks don't appear:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<td width="50%" nowrap="nowrap">
 <xsl:call-template name="split-parent" />
</td>

....

 <xsl:template match="STUDENT_DETAILS/PARENT" name ="split-parent">
    <xsl:variable name="splitParentsVar">
        <xsl:call-template name="add-line-breaks">
            <xsl:with-param name="stringToBreak" select="STUDENT_DETAILS/PARENT"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="isEven" select="0"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$splitParentsVar"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="add-line-breaks">
    <xsl:param name="stringToBreak"/>
    <xsl:param name ="isEven" />
    <xsl:if test ="$isEven='1'">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($stringToBreak,'&#xa;')"/>
        <xsl:if test="substring-after($stringToBreak,';')!=''">
            <xsl:call-template name="add-line-breaks">
                <xsl:with-param name="stringToBreak" select="substring-after($stringToBreak,';')"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="isEven" select="0"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$isEven='0'">
        <xsl:value-of select="$stringToBreak"/>
        <xsl:if test="substring-after($stringToBreak,';')!=''">
            <xsl:call-template name="add-line-breaks">
                <xsl:with-param name="stringToBreak" select="substring-after($stringToBreak,';')"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="isEven" select="1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
....
```

An example of the input would be:

George Aaron; Susan Lee Aaron; Richard Elliot Aaron; Albert Smith; Carry Johnson

output would be something like:

George Aaron; Susan Lee Aaron; 
Richard Elliot Aaron; Albert Smith; 
 Carry Johnson

The input XML looks something like this:

```
<NewDataSet>
    <REPORT_OPTIONS>
        <RANK_RUN>12/04/2013</RANK_RUN>
        <PRNT_WGHT_AVGE>False<PRNT_WGHT_RANK>
    </REPORT_OPTIONS>
    <STUDENT_DETAILS>
        <STUD_PK>1590</STUD_PK>
        <STUD_NAME>Robert SMith</STUD_NAME>
        <PARENT>jubju Aaron; Susan Lee Aaron; Richard Elliot Aaron; Carl Smith</PARENT>
    </STUDENT_DETAILS>
</NewDataSet>
```

I want to modify the `<PARENT>` tag so that every two parents there is a line break that will be rendered in HTML (Whatever the best way to do this is).

Comment: Please add samples of input, desired output and actual output.

Comment: I meant samples of the input, desired and actual output ***XML***

Answer (score 1):

Its an incomplete Input and Output XML. But the primary issue is that HTML and XHTML doesn't adhere to line breaks.

This code in XHTML:

```
<span>Hello


World

!</span>
```

Would be rendered as:

> Hello World !

To insert a line break in HTML, you'll need to output a `<br/>` tag where you want line breaks in the output page.

So you'd need to change this line:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($stringToBreak,'&#xa;')"/>
```

to this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$stringToBreak"/><br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Carried over from:

[hInserting line-break into XML so that it appears after XSL rendering in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356757/hinserting-line-break-into-xml-so-that-it-appears-after-xsl-rendering-in-vb-net)*

You are (again) making it very difficult to help you, because there is no context - like where does the table begin, for example. Anyway, try fitting these two templates into your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="STUDENT_DETAILS/PARENT">
    <td>
        <xsl:call-template name="break_even">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="';'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </td>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="break_even">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="','"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="
        contains($string, $delimiter) 
        and 
        contains(substring-after($string, $delimiter), $delimiter)">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(
            substring-before($string, $delimiter), $delimiter, 
            substring-before(substring-after($string, $delimiter), $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
            <br/>
            <xsl:call-template name="break_even">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after(substring-after($string, $delimiter),$delimiter)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```