# XSLT 1.0 Loop through comma separated element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

My XML includes an element like this...

```
<root>
    <data>
        <data_item>
            <colours>White, Red, Light Blue</colours>
        </data_item>
    </data>
</root>
```

I need to transform this into...

```
<Items>
    <item>
<custom_options>name=Options,type=multiple,required=0,price=0.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=White|name=Options,type=multiple,required=0,price=0.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Red|name=Options,type=multiple,required=0,price=0.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Light Blue</custom_options>
    </item>
</Items>
```

Comment: Actually this is mostly text transform and not xml transform so doing it in code may be better and easier. Doing it on XSLT 1.0 is a bit difficult (XSLT 2.0 has a built-in split function) but you can check this question which explains how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845660/xsl-how-to-split-strings

Comment: I have added this to xsl file..

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="split">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">
   <xsl:if test="not($pText=.)">
    <br />
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select=
    "substring-before(concat($pText,';'),';')"/>
   <xsl:call-template name="split">
    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
     "substring-after($pText, ';')"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

How do I insert the value-of into the element?
<custom_options>title:colours,name:blue|title:colours,name:red</custom_options>

Answer (score 4):

Create a recursive template to split a string, based on the separator:

```
<xsl:template name="splitter">
    <xsl:param name="remaining-string"/>
    <xsl:param name="pattern"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($remaining-string,$pattern)">
            <split-item>
                <xsl:value-of select = "normalize-space(substring-before($remaining-string,$pattern))"/>
            </split-item>
            <xsl:call-template name="splitter">
                <xsl:with-param name="remaining-string"  select="substring-after($remaining-string,$pattern)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pattern"  select="$pattern"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <split-item>
                <!-- normalize-space reduces a sequence of spaces to at most one space. Do your own stuff to format individual split item -->
                <xsl:value-of select = "normalize-space($remaining-string)"/>
            </split-item>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Call this template on the node which contains a sequence of items separated by a pattern:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name = "colors">
        <xsl:for-each select="root/data/data_item">
            <xsl:call-template name="splitter">
                <xsl:with-param name="remaining-string"  select="colours"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pattern"  select="','"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!--Do your thing with the variable colors. I simply send it to the output stream. If you further want to iterate over the split items, make sure you convert the variable to a node-set-->
    <xsl:copy-of select = "$colors"/>
</xsl:template>
```

See it in action here: http://xsltransform.net/ei5Pwj6