# XSLT: reading value as a list or array

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml element:

```
<myElement>item1 item2 item3</myElement>
```

I want to use XSLT to transform it to:

```
<newElement>item1</newElement>  
<newElement>item2</newElement>
<newElement>item3</newElement>
```

How woudl the xslt look? I am more interested in how to loop though the list of myElement or how to get it to become a list or variable.

Please advise.

Comment: Just one duplicate example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136500/does-xslt-have-a-split-function

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution. :)

Comment: With this kind of question you need to make it clear whether you want an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>


 <xsl:template match="text()[contains(., ' ')]" name="tokenize">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

  <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">
   <newElement>
    <xsl:value-of select=
     "substring-before(concat($pText,' '),' ')"/>
   </newElement>

   <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
     "substring-after($pText,' ')"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<myElement>item1 item2 item3</myElement>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<newElement>item1</newElement>
<newElement>item2</newElement>
<newElement>item3</newElement>
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0 it's easier:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="myElement">
   <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\s+')">
     <newElement><xsl:value-of select="."/></newElement>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```