# Line Break in XSLT for a comma separated value

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT and I am trying the following:

I have the following:

```
<TR> <TD> Name: </TD> <TD><xsl:value-of select="ZNAME"/> </TD> </TR>
```

which returns

```
ADAM,BRIAN,CHARLIE,DAVID
```

How I can make this return:

```
ADAM
BRIAN
CHARLIE
DAVID
```

Please suggest.

Comment: If you have this input `<ZNAME>ADAM,BRIAN,CHARLIE,DAVID</ZNAME>`, you are looking for tokenization. That would be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136500/does-xslt-have-a-split-function

Comment: @Alejandro - You should add that as an answer so you can get a proper upvote. @Portal Admin - Like Alejandro said, tokenization is the way to go. However, if you need to add a literal break in your output in some other circumstance, try using something like `<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>`.

Comment: @DevNull: Do note that `translate(ZNAME,',','&#xA;')` could be also a proper answer to this question **as is**.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="ZNAME" name="tokenize">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="concat(., ',')"/>

  <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)>0">
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, ',')"/>
   <br />
   <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:with-param name="pText"
     select="substring-after($pText, ',')"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document:**

```
<ZNAME>ADAM,BRIAN,CHARLIE,DAVID</ZNAME>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
ADAM<br/>BRIAN<br/>CHARLIE<br/>DAVID<br/>

which when viewed in a browser is displayed like:
```

ADAM
BRIAN
CHARLIE
DAVID

Answer (score 0):

If you need a solution that doesn't output a trailing `<br/>` element, try this:

```
<TR> <TD> Name: </TD> <TD><xsl:apply-templates select="ZNAME"/> </TD> </TR>

<xsl:template match="ZNAME" name="convertcommas">
  <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($text,','),',')" />
  <xsl:if test="contains($text,',')">
    <br />
    <xsl:call-template name="convertcommas">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,',')" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The `concat($text,',')` makes sure the `substring-before` sees at least one comma, thereby outputting the string on it's own if there were no commas originally.