# How do I extract a particular value in a comma delimited list in XLST and compare the value to another?

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT and have a similar requirement to [Line Break in XSLT for a comma separated value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121534/line-break-in-xslt-for-a-comma-separated-value) however I need to do the following

1. Check if the value is a single string e.g. Apples or whethe it is a comma delimited list e.g. Apples, Pears, etc
2. If it is a comma delimited list then check if the list has a particular value or values
3. If the value exists then do something
4. If it is a single string e.g. Apple then do something

How can I achieve this is XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tokenize the list. A function like this might do the job (embedded in a working XSLT for demonstration purposes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="NS:MY">
  <xsl:function name="my:test">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(normalize-space($string),'\s*,\s*')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="normalize-space($string)='Apples'">
        Do something where we have a single "Apples" 
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="normalize-space($string)='Pears'"> 
        Do something where we have a single "Pears" 
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$tokens='Apples' and $tokens='Pears'"> 
        There are Apples and Pears 
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$tokens='Apples'"> 
        There are Apples in the list 
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$tokens='Pears'"> 
        There are Pears in the list 
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise> 
        Didn't find what we're looking for 
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <out>
      <xsl:value-of select="my:test('Apples')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="my:test('Pears,Oranges')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="my:test(' Apples ,Pears,Oranges')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="my:test('Oranges , Bananas, Strawberries')"/>
    </out>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could also use [regular expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax).

See the XPath documentation for what [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-normalize-space) and [`tokenize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) do. You might want to replace the bogus namespace "NS:MY" with something sensible.

Comment: When I try `<xsl:variable name="fruits">Apples, Pears</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="tokenized" select="tokenize(normalize-space($fruits),'\s*,\s*')"/>
  
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="normalize-space($tokenized)='Apples' or normalize-space($tokenized)='Pears'">
     Do something where we have a single "Apples"
   </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>` as an example it fails. The error message is A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of normalize-space()

Comment: Yes, you should first do `normalize-space()` (to remove leading and trailing space if necessary) and then `tokenize()`. I added some more example code above.

Comment: Thanks Thomas but why does it give me an error when I use my example

Comment: `tokenize()` returns a sequence of strings. `noramlize-space()` expects a string and not sequence.

Comment: Thanks. I don't quite follow. I have a sequence which I normalize. Why would it then throw an error when I normalize it again?

Comment: You can't normalize a sequence. It's a construct comparable to an array. You can only normalize a string. (If your comma separated values strings are guaranteed to not have leading/trailing whitespace, then you don't have to normalize anything.)