# Needed XSLT for string split

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Im having data in XML has this

```
1 $ Mahesh $ SE $ ITO;2 $ umesh $ TE $ HBS;3 $ somesh$ SE $ ITO;
```

I have to split this string based on ';' and then each split string with '$'

I could able to do one level, but got strucked with next level of spplit

```
<xsl:template match="text()" name="split">
    <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">
        <xsl:if test="not($pText=.)">
            <br />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($pText,';'),';')"/>


        <xsl:call-template name="split">
            <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, ';')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617710/split-a-string-in-xslt) and http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[xslt]+split

Comment: Can u please tell me how to increase probability , i marked all question s  as answered, not sure what exactly ur expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="s">1 $ Mahesh $ SE $ ITO;2 $ umesh $ TE $ HBS;3 $ somesh$ SE $ ITO;</xsl:variable>

        <result>
            <xsl:call-template name="split">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$s"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="split">
        <xsl:param name="pText"/>

        <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">

            <group value="{substring-before($pText, ';')}">
                <xsl:call-template name="split2">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-before($pText, ';')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </group>

            <xsl:call-template name="split">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, ';')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="split2">
        <xsl:param name="pText"/>

        <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">
            <item>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($pText, '$')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($pText, '$'))"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($pText)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </item>

            <xsl:call-template name="split2">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '$')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>
  <group value="1 $ Mahesh $ SE $ ITO">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>Mahesh</item>
    <item>SE</item>
    <item>ITO</item>
  </group>
  <group value="2 $ umesh $ TE $ HBS">
    <item>2</item>
    <item>umesh</item>
    <item>TE</item>
    <item>HBS</item>
  </group>
  <group value="3 $ somesh$ SE $ ITO">
    <item>3</item>
    <item>somesh</item>
    <item>SE</item>
    <item>ITO</item>
  </group>
</result>
```