# Breaking up XML string in C#

Tags: c#, xml, string, xmlnode, innertext

I have got an XML node called 'structNumber' which has data similar to '4.2'

I select the node using:

```
XmlNode xnChapNr = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//./structNumber");
```

And at present I am displaying it by:

```
 string chapNr = (xnChapNr == null) ? "X" : xnChapNr.InnerText
```

This then displays the entire string '4.2'.

What I need however, is a way to only select the '4' for this string and the '2' for another.

Is there an extension for InnerText? I have read through the documentation but nothing appears to work as I wish it to.

If it is helpful to know; what this code does in its entirety is produce a tree structure of an XML document. I.e: 
Chapter 4,
 Section 4.1,
  Sub section 4.1.1,
 Section 4.2,
ect...

Any and all help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't `Split` do what you want?  `string[] chapNrs = (xnChapNr ?? "").Split(".".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`  After this the array will either be empty or contain one or more chapter numbers.  Then you can print 'X' if `.Length==0` or do whatever else it is you intend to do with the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string chapNr = (xnChapNr == null) ? "X" : xnChapNr.InnerText.ToString().Split(new char[]{'.'})[0]` will return you 4 and

`string chapNr = (xnChapNr == null) ? "X" : xnChapNr.InnerText.ToString().Split(new char[]{'.'})[1]` will return you 2

Comment: Thank you very much! Its so simple when you see it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is not related to XML but to String operation. What you are looking for is the Split function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

Comment: Although note it can be achieved with XSLT if he's happy altering the XML structure first:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136500/does-xslt-have-a-split-function

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use XSLT, I hadn't even considered that. However, in this case I think it is easier to just use Split like yourself and the others have suggested.