# how to make xsl tokenize work

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a huge xsl file but the section where i use "tokenize" to parse through a comma separated string is throwing an error. For simplicity purposes I have broke it down to just test the tokenize piece only and cannot seem to make any progress. I keep getting the following error:

> Expression expected. tokenize(-->[<--text],',')

I tried using some example xsl shared in other posts but never managed to get it to work. I am having a difficult time understanding why my xsl code below is not valid. It seems t be very straightforward but I think I am missing something simple. Any help to get me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/root">
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize([text],',')"/>
<items>
<item>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</item>
</items>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="simple.xsl"?>
<root>
<text>Item1, Item2, Item3</text>
</root>
```

I am expecting an XML output as follows:

```
<items>
<item>Item1</item>
<item>Item2</item>
<item>Item3</item>
</items>
```

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does XSLT have a Split() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136500/does-xslt-have-a-split-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated by DevNull, tokenize() is an XSLT 2.0 function. However, if your processor supports EXSLT, use can use the [str:tokenize() function](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html). Otherwise you will need to user recursion to split your comma separated values like thus ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
 <items>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="root/text"/>
 </items>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
 <xsl:call-template name="tokenize"> 
   <xsl:with-param name="csv" select="." /> 
 </xsl:call-template>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
 <xsl:param name="csv" />
  <xsl:variable name="first-item" select="normalize-space( 
    substring-before( concat( $csv, ','), ','))" /> 
 <xsl:if test="$first-item">
  <item>
   <xsl:value-of select="$first-item" /> 
  </item>  
  <xsl:call-template name="tokenize"> 
   <xsl:with-param name="csv" select="substring-after($csv,',')" /> 
  </xsl:call-template>    
 </xsl:if>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The above solution assumes that there are no empty items in the list.

Comment: +1. You just saved me a day of banging my head on a wall esp. since you gave the link to the Exslt tokenize function.

Answer (score 11):

I see 4 things wrong:

1. You're using `tokenize()` in a 1.0 stylesheet. You need to change the version to 2.0 and use a 2.0 processor. If you're using a web browser to do the transform, based on the `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction, you're probably not using a 2.0 processor.
2. The first argument of your tokenize (`[text]`) is invalid. Just use `text`.
3. You've prematurely closed your `xsl:for-each`.
4. You're outputting an `<items>` for each item. Put the `<items>` outside the `xsl:for-each`.

Example of changes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <items>
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(text,',')">
                <item>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </items>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To truly get your desired output with a 2.0 processor, I'd also suggest using `xsl:output` and `normalize-space()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <items>
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(text,',')">
                <item>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                </item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </items>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks DevNull. This was very helpful. My last question....how would i know what processor i am using? Is there a way to confirm that somewhere?

Comment: Call functions system-property('xsl:vendor') and system-property('xsl:version'). These return strings. Output them.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! It appears that i have 1.0 processor. How would I upgrade this?